# Not understanding how UIActivityIndicatorView works with NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, nstimer, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm missing something about how `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `NSTimer` work together.

I've added this `UIActivityIndicatorView` in Interface Builder with the following settings:

[image: UIActivityIndicatorView]
[image: UIActivityIndicatorView settings]

The `UIWebView` is instantiated as `self.webV` and the `UIActivityIndicatorView` as `self.indicator`.

I have the following code in the implementation file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create UIWebView.
    if (!self.webV)
    {
        self.webV = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
}
    self.webV.delegate = self;

//Load web page.

    NSString *baseURLString = @"myURL.com";
    NSString *urlString = [baseURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myURL.com"];

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/2.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self connectWithURL:urlString andBaseURLString:baseURLString];
}

-(void)timerLoad
{
    if (!self.webV.loading)
    {
        [self.indicator stopAnimating];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.indicator startAnimating];
    }
}
```

But when the `UIWebView` loads, no activity indicator shows up.  What am I doing wrong or leaving out?

Thanks for the help, folks.

Comment: is the indicator visible?  is it on top of the web view in the view hierarchy?

Comment: Put a log statement into the else clause to see if the code ever reaches that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not sure on what the behaviour of the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is supposed to be if you repeatedly call start/stop on it. I am reasonably sure it isn't meant to be used that way :)

So, even though your question is specific to `NSTimer` and `UIActivityIndicatorView`, it may be helpful to understand that you should approach your solution differently.

Instead of using a timer that repeatedly calls `[self.indicator startAnimating]` every half-second, you should use the webview delegate methods to toggle the `UIActivityIndicatorView` on and off.

```
       -(void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            //Create UIWebView.
            if (!self.webV)
            {
                self.webV = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
            }
            self.webV.delegate = self;

        //Load web page.

            NSString *baseURLString = @"myURL.com";
            NSString *urlString = [baseURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myURL.com"];

            //self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/2.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerLoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

            [self connectWithURL:urlString andBaseURLString:baseURLString];
        }

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
      //start animating
      [self.indicator startAnimating];
 }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
         //stop animating
         [self.indicator stopAnimating];
    }
```

Comment: That's what I get for watching YouTube Xcode "tutorials"....  Thanks so very much.

Answer (score 3):

There could be several reasons. It could load so fast that the loading is already done, or it never loaded at all because something is wrong with the URL.

This isn't the cause of your problem, but you never invalidate your timer, which you should.

I was also going to make the point that you should use delegate methods instead of a timer, but pdriegen beat me to it.